# Virtual file for AES/SHA1 kernel side computing

Tags: performance, encryption, udev

Is there a file (in /dev perhaps) that allows me to compute AES or SHA1 on data? There are analogs like `/dev/urandom /dev/zero` etc.

It would work like this: open said file, write data to it and read results out of it. Using `sendfile` syscall would be useful here as well, copying data directly within kernel space.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote. Its a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as a device node. There is an interface to the kernel CryptoAPI, but it's through netlink (AF_ALG). [More information is available in the Linux kernel documentation.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e63b673f601dda77c668e6fd5240425b5331ec7f/Documentation/crypto/crypto-API-userspace.txt)

However, it is rarely useful unless you have a hardware crypto accelerator which is only available from the kernel. The overhead of system calls will often make this interface much slower than performing crypto operations directly in your process.